# Generate dropdowlist with data json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json data like this:

```
 var data = [
        {ID:"1", Name: "a", ParentID: 0},
        {ID:"2", Name: "b", ParentID: 0},
        {ID:"3", Name: "c", ParentID: 0},
        {ID:"4", Name: "aa", ParentID: 1},
        {ID:"5", Name: "aaa", ParentID: 1},
        {ID:"6", Name: "bb", ParentID: 2},
        {ID:"7", Name: "cc", ParentID: 3},
        {ID:"8", Name: "bbb", ParentID: 2},
        {ID:"9", Name: "ccc", ParentID: 3},
        {ID:"10", Name: "bbbb", ParentID: 2},
        {ID:"11", Name: "cccc", ParentID: 3}
    ]
```

I want to use Javascript Jquery for generating to dropdownlist. 
Note: Data sort base on parentID
ex: ID = ParentID

```
  {ID:"1", Name: "a", ParentID: 0},
        {ID:"4", Name: "aa", ParentID: 1},
        {ID:"5", Name: "aaa", ParentID: 1}
```

I expect result as this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="4">aa</option>
    <option value="5">aaa</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="6">bb</option>
    <option value="8">bbb</option>
    <option value="10">bbbb</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
    <option value="7">cc</option>
    <option value="9">ccc</option>
    <option value="11">cccc</option>
</select>
```

How can i do?

Thanks all,

Comment: just loop until you have values in data array and create option tag for each value found in the data array.

Comment: You will get an error in the console like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { ` for your **data** object! Please check if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 2):

Use json array notation e.g.

```
var data = [
    {ID:"1", Name: "a", ParentID: 0},
    {ID:"2", Name: "b", ParentID: 0}
];
```

If you're using jQuery...

```
if(data.length){
    var elem = $('<select>');
    $.each(data, function(key,value){
       elem.append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",value.ID)
         .text(value.Name));
    });

   $('body').append(elem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this one. Just make data an array and remove a trailing comma:

```
var data = [
        {ID:"1", Name: "a", ParentID: 0},
        {ID:"2", Name: "b", ParentID: 0},
        {ID:"3", Name: "c", ParentID: 0},
        {ID:"4", Name: "aa", ParentID: 1},
        {ID:"5", Name: "aaa", ParentID: 1},
        {ID:"6", Name: "bb", ParentID: 2},
        {ID:"7", Name: "cc", ParentID: 3},
        {ID:"8", Name: "bbb", ParentID: 2},
        {ID:"9", Name: "ccc", ParentID: 3},
        {ID:"10", Name: "bbbb", ParentID: 2},
        {ID:"11", Name: "cccc", ParentID: 3}
    ],
    selectHtml,
    optionArr = [];

optionArr.push('<select>');
for (var i = 0, il = data.length; i < il; i++) {
    optionArr.push('<option value="' + data[i].ID + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>');
}
optionArr.push('</select>');
selectHtml = optionArr.join('');
console.log(selectHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your data an array of objects:

```
var data = [
    {ID:"1", Name: "a", ParentID: 0},
    {ID:"2", Name: "b", ParentID: 0}, ...
];
```

Sort data based on ParentID: 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3

```
var sorted = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
  sorted[i] = data.filter(function(datum) {
    return datum.ParentID === i;
  });
}
//each sorted[index] contains an array having same ParentIDs
var zeroes = sorted.splice(0, 1)[0]; //remove the first array which contains objects with ParentID === 0
```

Have an empty select element in your markup:

```
<select id="data"></select>
```

Create an `option` from each data element and append it to `select`.

```
zeroes.forEach(function(z, index) { //iterate over objects with ParentID === 0
    addOption(z);
    sorted[index].forEach(function(datum) { //iterate over non-zero ParentIDs
        addOption(datum);
    });
});

function addOption(obj) {
    var option = $('<option></option>').attr('value', obj.ID).text(obj.Name);
    $('#data').append(option);
}
```

**[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6BN2/1/)**

Comment: Thank for your idea but I want to sort data base on parentID. it likes this: {ID:"1", Name: "a", ParentID: 0},
 {ID:"4", Name: "aa", ParentID: 1},
 {ID:"5", Name: "bca", ParentID: 1},
 {ID:"2", Name: "b", ParentID: 0},
 {ID:"6", Name: "bb", ParentID: 2},
 {ID:"8", Name: "aab", ParentID: 2},
 {ID:"10", Name: "bbbb", ParentID: 2}

Comment: @CaroloLe please check the updated version. I presume it does that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it jQuery template.

**Pre-requisites**

jquery.tmpl.min.js. Download from [here](http://my-web-js.googlecode.com/files/jquery.tmpl.min.js)

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectmenu"></select>
```

**Template**

Prepare template that you want to repeat. Its works like item template.

```
<script id="optionTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
     <option value='${ID}'>${Name}</option>
</script>
```

**Javascript**
Data prepared by you was wrong. You need that in array object.

```
var data = 
 [{ID:"1", Name: "a", ParentID: 0},
 {ID:"2", Name: "b", ParentID: 0},
 {ID:"3", Name: "c", ParentID: 0},
 {ID:"4", Name: "aa", ParentID: 1},
 {ID:"5", Name: "aaa", ParentID: 1},
 {ID:"6", Name: "bb", ParentID: 2},
 {ID:"7", Name: "cc", ParentID: 3},
 {ID:"8", Name: "bbb", ParentID: 2},
 {ID:"9", Name: "ccc", ParentID: 3},
 {ID:"10", Name: "bbbb", ParentID: 2},
 {ID:"11", Name: "cccc", ParentID: 3}];
```

**jQuery**
To create a list from template and data, you need to used tmpl() method.

```
$('#optionTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#selectmenu');
```

Explanation

*optionTemplate*: name of item template

*selectmenu*: is the ID of the select HTML control

*data*: is array of javascript

**Output**

[image]

Check out [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/den9W/2/)

Queries welcomed!